# Read The Docs Not Building Project Documentation After Creation via Web Interface

Tags: python, documentation, rtd

I am using Read The Docs to build the documentation for my project. I followed the [documentation](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) to install the software, and after trying to import documentation from a project using these [instructions](https://read-the-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#import-your-docs), no build job ran. I checked the log file for any problems and there was no indication that a build even started. I then manually tried to start a build using slumber 0.4.2 (recommended version of slumber for RTD), but it failed, because it had a bug in which its HTTP requests included the http:// prefix and thus caused a 404 error even though the webpage it attempted to access actually existed. I then updated slumber to version 0.5.3, but then I received the following error from RTD:

```
File "/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/projects/tasks.py", line 158, in update_docs
    build['state'] = 'building'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

How should I deal with this issue?